# Ubuntu 22.04 - Bluetooth failed to start after working fine for a long time

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

Since about two years ago, bluetooth was working fine within Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 until few days ago, bluetooth failed to start. I don't know what happened. It's integrated bluetooth.

The following output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
```

So I had checked typing `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`, the output is the following:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-08-07 20:26:16 -05; 6min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1071 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8852)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 166ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1071 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

ago 07 20:26:16 zhu-PCG02-GLE systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
ago 07 20:26:16 zhu-PCG02-GLE bluetoothd[1071]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
ago 07 20:26:16 zhu-PCG02-GLE systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
ago 07 20:26:16 zhu-PCG02-GLE bluetoothd[1071]: Starting SDP server
ago 07 20:26:16 zhu-PCG02-GLE bluetoothd[1071]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

Then, I typed `sudo dmesg|grep -i bluetooth`, the output is the following:

```
[   13.508408] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   13.508459] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   13.508462] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.508469] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.508473] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.508479] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.598909] Bluetooth: hci0: sending initial HCI reset failed (-19)
[   17.932872] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.932882] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   17.932889] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.797524] Bluetooth: hci0: sending initial HCI reset failed (-19)
[   22.002137] Bluetooth: hci0: sending initial HCI reset failed (-19)
[   24.213707] Bluetooth: hci0: sending initial HCI reset failed (-19)
[ so on... ]
```

Does anyone advice me?

Comment: Ubuntu just solved that problem itself after few days, I have no idea why.